# how to fix NoReverseMatch at? work if you not authorized

Tags: django, view, django-views, url-routing

> If you are not authorized, then everything will work fine, as soon as
>   you authorize, for example, adeline, this error will be issued, I do
>   not know what happened!

NoReverseMatch at /series/Colony/Season_1/Episode_1/

```
Reverse for 'post_of_serie' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['series/(?P<serial_slug>[\\w-]+)/(?P<season_slug>[\\w-]+)/(?P<series_slug>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^series/', include("serials.urls", namespace='series')),
    url(r'^', include("serials.urls", namespace='homeview')),



]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

second urls.py to app(series)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import homeview, post_of_serial, post_of_season, post_of_serie, validate_email, mark_and_unmark_this_episode

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', homeview, name='homeview'),
   url(r'^subscribe/$', validate_email, name='subscribe'),   # /series/
   url(r'^mark_or_unmark_this_episode/$', mark_and_unmark_this_episode, name="mark_and_unmark_this_episode"),
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_serial, name='post_of_serial'),  # /series/Prison_Break/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<season_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_season, name='post_of_season'),  # /series/Prison_Break/season_5/
   url(r'^(?P<serial_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<season_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<series_slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_of_serie, name='post_of_serie'),  # /series/Prison_Break/season_5/2/  
]
```

error [image: ERROR]

this is part of view.py

```
def post_of_serie(request, serial_slug=None, season_slug=None, series_slug=None):
    serie                           = get_object_or_404(Series, serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, slug=series_slug)
    #print(serie)
    title                           = serie.serial_of_this_series.rus_name_of_seriall
    full_path                       = All_Images_Of_The_Series.objects.filter(to_series__serial_of_this_series__slug=serial_slug, to_series__season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, to_series__slug=series_slug, is_poster=True)

    context = {"serie":serie, "full_path":full_path, "title":title,}
    try:
        userr                       = request.user          
        check_button                = watched_series.objects.filter(user=request.user, watched_serial__slug=serial_slug, watched_serie__season_of_this_series__slug=season_slug, watched_serie__slug=series_slug )
        context["check_button"]     = check_button
        context["userr"]            = userr
    except:
        pass


    return render(request, 'series.html', context)
```

if delete somethig in views.py nothing change!!!

main html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>{{ title }}</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static "css/footer.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{% static "css/main.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">
        {% block styles %}{% endblock styles %}


    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="{{ advertise_for_header.link_for_advertise }}"><div class="advertises" ></div></a>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="wrapper-content">
            {% include "navbar.html" %}
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
            </div>
            {% include "footer.html" %}
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js"%}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/smooth-scroll.js"%}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "js/script.js" %}"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

series.html where is up error!

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 her">
                <span class="links" >
                    <a class="a-link" href="{{ serie.serial_of_this_series.get_absolute_url }}">{{ serie.serial_of_this_series.rus_name_of_seriall }} <img src="{% static "img/breadcrumbs-arrow.png" %}" class="arrow"  > </a>

                    <a class="a-link" href="{{ serie.season_of_this_series.get_absolute_url }}">{{ serie.season_of_this_series.name_of_the_season }}<img src="{% static "img/breadcrumbs-arrow.png" %}" class="arrow"  ></a>

                    <a class="a-link" href="{{ serie.get_absolute_url }}">{{ serie.rus_name }}<img src="{% static "img/breadcrumbs-arrow.png" %}" class="arrow"  ></a>
                </span>

                <div class="title-block" >
                    <h3 class="seria-header">
                        <img src="{{ serie.serial_of_this_series.preview_of_serial.url }}" class="thumb">
                        <span class="titles" >
                            <div class="title-ru">{{ serie.rus_name }}</div>
                            <div class="title-en">{{ serie.eng_name }}</div>
                        </span>
                    </h3>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <form class="watch_button" method="POST" action="{% url 'series:post_of_serie' %}" > {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="buttons" >
                                <div class="second_section_of_buttons" >
                                    {% if check_button %}
                                        <div class="isawthat-btn checcked" title="Серия просмотрена. Убрать пометку?" ><img src="{% static "img/white-eye-icon.png" %}" class="iccon"/><span class="text_button" >Серия просмотрена</span></div>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <div class="isawthat-btn" title="Пометить серию как просмотренную" ><img src="{% static "img/pink-eye-icon.png" %}" class="iccon"/><span class="text_button" >Серия Не просмотрена</span></div>
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <p class="user hidden" >{{ userr }}</p>
                            <p class="watched_serial hidden" >{{ serie.serial_of_this_series }}</p>
                            <p class="watched_serie hidden" >{{ serie }}</p>
                            <p class="minutes_of_series hidden" >{{ serie }}</p>
                            <p class="serial_slug hidden" > {{ serie.serial_of_this_series.slug }} </p>
                            <p class="season_slug hidden" > {{ serie.season_of_this_series.slug }} </p>
                            <p class="series_slug hidden" > {{ serie.slug }} </p>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: The error is clear, you're not passing any arguments to your URL tag but the "post_of_serie" requires three. The error is also clearly happening in the template, which you haven't shown.

Comment: man again you, i can read!!!!!!!!! I'm not stupid, I know that he asks for 3, so these 3 and are transferred, and I can read how many times I asked you, do not write anything to me, there's still no point, you write that I myself see it !!!! !!!! Before coming here, I myself sit and try to fix it, I can not go here, do not write to me !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form class="watch_button" method="POST" action="{% url 'series:post_of_serie' %}" >
```

this is the line you are having the error bro, see, this form appears only for logged in user, and you dont have a view like `def post_of_serie(request):`

try to pass the slugs here in the form url, then the problem will be solved

Comment: didn't work again, try and ecept works briliant, this error!This error got out just from somewhere, all the code is correct, everything is transferred, just a bug somewhere, or it's a bit dull!

Comment: do one thing, post your html,

Comment: As I said, that if I'm not authorized, then everything will work fine, because the code is correct!

Comment: that means the try part is having the problem.remove that part and login and check once, i guess the filter query is returning multiple objects

Comment: i try delete everuything in try and execpt nothing!

Comment: I apologize, I tried to fix the Ajax code for this button, and changed the function, it was evening, and I decided to fix the destination url tomorrow)) thanks!

Comment: no need to apologize bro, it happens sometimes, happy to help :)